# Шифрование в Delphi используя XOR

Tags: delphi, шифрование

Здравтсвуйте!

Пытаюсь взять файл с текстом и шифровать его так:

```
function Encode(Source, Key: AnsiString): AnsiString;
var
  i: Integer;
  s: Byte;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := 1 to Length(Source) do
  begin
    if Length(Key) > 0 then
      s := Byte(Key[1 + ((i - 1) mod Length(Key))]) xor Byte(Source[i])
    else
      s := Byte(Source[i]);
    Result := Result + AnsiLowerCase(IntToHex(s, 2));
  end;
end;
```

И снова его дешифровать так:

```
function Decode(Source, Key: AnsiString): AnsiString;
var
  i: Integer;
  s: AnsiChar;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := 0 to Length(Source) div 2 - 1 do
  begin
    s := AnsiChar(StrToIntDef('$' + Copy(Source, (i * 2) + 1, 2), Ord(' ')));
    if Length(Key) > 0 then
      s := AnsiChar(Byte(Key[1 + (i mod Length(Key))]) xor Byte(s));
    Result := Result + s;
  end;
end;
```

Шифрует и дешифрует, НО добавляет к дешифрованному тексту в конец символы
что-то вроде:
<0x17> или <0x12>

Помогите решить вопрос с корректным шифрованием и дешифрованием текста

Пример:
при попытке шифровать кусок вида (ключ - N90fL6FF9SXx+S):

```
select object_schema_name(so.[object_id]) as [schema]
      ,so.[name]
      ,so.[type]
      ,so.[type_desc]
      ,so.create_date
      ,so.modify_date
      ,def.od
from sys.objects so
    inner join (select object_definition(object_id) as od
                     , object_id
                from sys.procedures) def
        on ( so.object_id = def.object_id )
where so.modify_date >= '2018-04-01'
    and (so.[type] = 'fn'
      or so.[type] = 'p')
```

он дешифруется как:

```
select object_schema_name(so.[object_id]) as [schema]
      ,so.[name]
      ,so.[type]
      ,so.[type_desc]
      ,so.create_date
      ,so.modify_date
      ,def.od
from sys.objects so
    inner join (select object_definition(object_id) as od
                     , object_id
                from sys.procedures) def
        on ( so.object_id = def.object_id )
where so.modify_date >= '2018-04-01'
    and (so.[type] = 'fn'
      or so.[type] = 'p')X
```

Как видно в конце появился символ X, т.е. при шифровании разными ключами или разных текстов, разные символы в конце. Если проделать шифрование->дешифрование несколько раз над тем же текстом, то в конце появится ровно столько символов сколько раз выполнено дешифрование.

Вызов шифрования:

```
var
  SQLtxt: TStringlist;
begin
  SQLtxt := TStringlist.create;
  try
    SQLm := 'N90fL6FF9SXx+S'; // Ключ
    SQLtxt.Text := Encode(Memo1.Text, SQLm);
    SQLtxt.SaveToFile(extractfilepath(paramstr(0)) + 'encode\pz.sq');
  finally
    SQLtxt.Free
  end;
end;
```

Вызов дешифрования:

```
var
  SQLtxt: TStringlist;
begin
  SQLtxt := TStringlist.create;
  try
    SQLm := 'N90fL6FF9SXx+S'; // Ключ
    Memo1.Clear;
    SQLtxt.LoadFromFile(extractfilepath(paramstr(0)) + 'encode\pz.sq');
    SQLtxt.Text := Decode(SQLtxt.Text, SQLm);
    Memo1.Text := SQLtxt.Text;
  finally
    SQLtxt.Free
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Эти два символа, не за-xor-енный вами перенос стройки случайно?

Comment: Похоже, что все у вас корректно, последние 2 символа - это зашифрованные символы конца строки $0D и $0A. Удаляйте эти символы из конца строки перед шифрованием/дешифрованием, если их не нужно обрабатывать. Например, функцией `Trim`. Или напишите в вопросе что вы хотите видеть в результате.

Comment: Если конец строки, то почему _"или"_. конец строки же парой `#13#10` в винде обозначается, так что и на выходе должно быть 2 символа, а не "или".  И добавляет-то к дешифрованному.

Comment: Как выглядит вызов функций шифрования и дешифрования? Какая длина  результата при шифровке короткой строки, скажем, длиной 4? Дебаг проводился?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не переделывайте вопрос на который был дан (правильный) ответ. Вы тем самым делаете ответ "неправильным". Задайте новый вопрос по новой проблеме, а этот вопрос верните к исходному состоянию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это переносы строк.

В коде, который теперь показан, используется не просто строка, а `SQLtxt.Text`.
Если выполнить дебаг с короткой входной строчкой, то можно увидеть, что на выходе `Encode` в строке лежит только то, что положено, а после присвоения `SQLtxt.Text` добавляется перенос строки `#$D#$A`.

Так что самое простое исправление (в cлучае, если SQLtxt не разбился на строки по возникшим в коде шифрования спецсимволам) - `Decode(SQLtxt[0], SQLm);`

И вообще избавляйтесь от использования свойства `Text` там, где оно не оправдано.